# Good Practice to always have a DLQ for lambda subscribed to SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Whenever lambda is subscribed to a SNS Topic/Kinesis stream, is it a good practice to always attach a DLQ to lambda so that we do not lose the messages in case the lambda is not able to process in its retries also that particular message.

Comment: If losing a message is a problem for your application, then yes, you should always attach a DLQ.

Comment: yes, definitely. Doing this specially helped us identify and solve the unhappy flows in the application faster and even automate them to some extent.

Comment: How about DLQ for SNS itself?